# Getting an image from localhost gives 404 with NodeJS and Express

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I implemented an upload of images in NodeJS express using multer, and when I try to get the images in the browser I got this error:

```
URL: http://localhost:5500/images/posts/5e2843e4efa65f188fc5552f.png
Cannot GET /images/posts/5e2843e4efa65f188fc5552f.png
```

I saw in the console the `404` so I cannot get why I can not see my image.

I did the upload in this way:

```
postRouter.post(
    "/:id/uploadImg",
    multerConfig.single("image"),
    async (req, res) => {
        try {
            const fileName =
                req.params.id + path.extname(req.file.originalname);

            const newImageLocation = path.join(
                __dirname,
                "../../images/posts",
                fileName
            );

            await fs.writeFile(newImageLocation, req.file.buffer);

            req.body.image =
                req.protocol +
                "://" +
                req.get("host") +
                "/images/posts/" +
                fileName;

            const newPostImg = await Posts.findOneAndUpdate(
                { _id: req.params.id },
                {
                    $set: { image: req.body.image }
                }
            );

            newPostImg.save();

            res.send("Image URL updated");
        } catch (ex) {
            res.status(500).send({ Message: "Internal server error", err: ex });
        }
    }
);
```

And in my server.js

```
server.use(express.static("./images"));
```

I'm able to upload but then not able to see it and cannot figure out what is the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you wrote `server.use(express.static("./images"));` you told your server to search for dir's and files **starting** from the `ìmages` folder on your app.

Therefore you should go to `http://localhost:5500/posts/5e2843e4efa65f188fc5552f.png` to search for your uploaded file. Assuming there's no other matching route before  `server.use(express.static("./images"));`.

**EDIT:**

If you want to be able to use the path you are already using, you should change your images directory like this:

```
--images
  --images
    --posts
      -photo.png
```

And change the path where your multer code saves the file like this:

```
const newImageLocation = path.join(
                __dirname,
                "../../images/images/posts",
                fileName
            );
```

Comment: That worked but hot to have the path as I save to server:
http://localhost:5500/images/posts/5e2843e4efa65f188fc5552f.png

Comment: if i understood you correctly, to save the image and access it by `/images/posts/....png` you should create a new `images` folder inside the old `images` folder and adjust your multer code so it saves the file in this new path.

Comment: The folder already exists so what I should change in my code above to get it in this way

Comment: Just edited the answer for you, hope it gets your upvote.

Comment: But for real is not possible to just have images/post or else so everytime have to be duplicated?